# Getting Like and Comment

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `facebook PHP SDK , facebook api version 2.2.`

I want to display the user news feed. I'm using the following api get this.

```
 $facebookConncetion->api("$oauthUserId/home",
    'GET',
    array("access_token" => $accessToken,
        "limit" => '15',
        "comments.limit" => 10,
        "likes.limit" => 10 
    ) 
);
```

But it returns all the post in the user home page with 10 comment and 10 likes and it does not return summary of like and comment. How can I format this api to get the like and comment summary per post?

Comment: Dare I say it....yes I do ... so you are doing it wrong!

Comment: could u please tell how to get summary also

Comment: php sdk 2.2? does that even exist anymore?

Comment: sorry, facebook graph api version 2.2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `.summary(true)` and `.filter(stream)` to the like and comment request just like you added the limit.

Summary will return something like this:

`"comments" : {
    "data" : [ ARRAY OF COMMENTS ] },
    "paging" : { PAGING CURSORS/URLS }.
    "summary" : {
         "total_count" : NUMBER OF COMMENTS
         }
     },`

Adding `.filter(stream)` will return ALL comments/likes. With out this there may be some missing due to Facebook filtering them out due to their low "story" value. It will also order all comments/likes in true chronological order.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments
Look under "Modifiers" works with both comments and likes.